# Fetch and function error on AJAX and APIs call on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ajax, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm getting an error of `items.map is not a function` when fetching the file that is hosted from unsplash.

I'm not sure if the problem is from the `.map` or from fetching the file from source.

Below is my code and also here is the complete sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ajax-api-95m7r?file=/src/components/data.js).

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=nature?orientation=landscape&client_id=ddIh7_ebg4KwNHzNLf3ePCZb6yIPREJ5jxG3dYgoj6U"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) =>
          <li key={item.results.id}>
            {item.results.description}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the response JSON is an object and not an array. When you update the `items` state with an object it's no longer mappable.

> ```
> // 20220209004834
> // https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=nature?orientation=landscape&client_id=ddIh7_ebg4KwNHzNLf3ePCZb6yIPREJ5jxG3dYgoj6U#f3f3f3
>
> {
>   "total": 10000,
>   "total_pages": 1000,
>   "results": [
>     {
>       "id": "_LuLiJc1cdo",
>       "created_at": "2016-06-06T01:08:36-04:00",
>       "updated_at": "2022-02-08T13:00:46-05:00",
>       "promoted_at": "2016-06-06T01:08:36-04:00",
>       ...
>       "description": "follow @kalenemsley on ig",
>       ...
>     },
>     ...
>   ],
>   ...
> }
> ```

You probably want the `results` array property for your state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("....")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setItems(result.results);
      },
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setError(error);
      }
    );
}, []);
```

***Then*** when mapping each item you access the properties correctly

```
<ul>
  {items.map((item) =>
    <li key={item.id}>
      {item.description}
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit fetch-and-function-error-on-ajax-and-apis-call-on-reactjs]

Comment: I already made a workaround on my local, but your solution is pretty simple and off course its working..thx!